# Listing indentation for long titles in Latex (listings package)

Tags: latex, listings

I have an indentation problem with LateX and the `listings` package.
I'm using `article` as document class and am using the following commands to set the indentation for tables and figures:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abb. }
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Abb. 9.999\quad}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Abb. 9.999\quad}
```

I've defined the indentation for the first line of listing captions via
`\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}{Lst. #1}{#2}}`

But I would like to also have the second line (I have some long captions that result in line breaks) having the same indentation. What can I do to have them aligned in the same way?

[image: Correct Indentation for figures and tables]

[image: Listing indentation]

I tried setting other values for `\dottedtocline`. But I can't force the second line of my listing captions to be aligned with the first one. I tried to find an equivalent to `\cftfignumwidth` or `\cfttabnumwidth` but there is none as the list of listings is generated in a different way.

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]?